# Connect to resource over VPN from windows container

Tags: docker, windows-container

I am trying to access resources over a corporate VPN from a windows container but cannot. When connected to the VPN, I can reach them just fine from the host (windows 10), but not from the container. It's not just name resolution, I cannot access these resources by IP either.

Over the past week I’ve read all about different network types with regards to windows containers, but I cannot seem to create a network with any driver other than `nat`. It seems that `l2bridge` may be the appropriate choice as it spoofs the mac address of the host (if I’ve read that correctly) but whenever I try to create to create that network, I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker network create -d l2bridge test --subnet 192.168.111.0/24 
Error response from daemon: hnsCall failed in Win32: Element not found. (0x490)
```

Most of the documentation I’ve found on this network type looks to be from 2018 and potentially outdated? I have no idea - I’m completely new to docker.

So, my questions:

1. Is a network with the `l2bridge` driver necessary to enable this communication over the VPN?
2. Is there some other method to enable this communication? This seems to work OOTB with linux containers and the `bridge` network, but there appear to be more hoops with windows containers…

Thanks!